# c# tracing system.diagnostics

Tags: c#, web-config, trace, system.diagnostics

I am using a sync service to sync between compact database and server. In web.config, i am diagnosing the sync and logging in the file like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
         <listeners>
            <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\MISTYLogs\SYNCService\syncTraces.svclog"></add>
         </listeners>
      </source>
   </sources>
   <switches>
      <add name="SyncTracer" value="3"/>
   </switches>
   <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
         <add name="SyncListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\MISTYLogs\SYNCService\syncinf.txt"/>
      </listeners>
   </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

During sync process, the file size becomes more than one gb. I want to restrict the log file size to some limit and after crossing that limit, it should create another log file and so on. How to achieve this using configuration settings??

Kindly suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using the [FileLogTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.filelogtracelistener.aspx).

> The FileLogTraceListener class
>   provides automated maintenance
>   capabilities to archive log files as
>   needed, on a daily or per-application
>   basis. This automatic archival
>   functionality helps reduce the
>   maintenance responsibilities of
>   developers and administrators.

Comment: Cheers! I never knew about it.

Comment: Makes you wonder what other gems might be hidden in the VB namespaces :)

Comment: I tried the FileLogTraceListener. but could not able to use as per the my requirement as asked in my question. Kindly Suggest?

Comment: Either use something like log4net, or create your own trace listener with rotation according to the rules you need.